# c++ malloc and two-dimension array not reserving enough memory

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I need to creat a 2 dimension array with malloc, so that I can return it's pointer with a function. In this function I also allocate integers (by getpixel() function) into this array. I do it this way:

```
int **tab;
tab = (int**)malloc((600) * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i<600; i++)
{
    tab[i] = (int*)malloc((800) * sizeof(int*));
}


for (int i = 0; i<600; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<800; j++)
    {
        tab[i][j] = getpixel(i, j);
    }
}
```

This array works of course in most of the cases, when I check it, it has the values I expected inside. However, it stops working, when I get to a bigger Y. So eg. when I want to check array tab[799][599], I can't, because there is an error about exception, I can't copy it directly, because I have the other language than English verion, but it goes something like that:

"The unsupported exception in 0x00E71C05 w bgi.exe: 0xC0000005: violation of rules of access when reading from the location 0x0000095C."

I think it means, that mallock() didn't reserve enought memory for me. But how can I make array big enough then? Or is this any other problem?

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++, use `new`

Comment: Or better yet, use a container from the STL, or a smart pointer. Avoid managing memory manually if you can!

Comment: `tab[799][599]` is not valid, first index should be up to 599, SECOND is up to 799. Take a loot at your second double loop, which also reflects that

Comment: You swapped your `sizeof`s.

Comment: It looks like there is another problem, namely Turbo C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your malloc is wrong, it needs to be like:

```
int **tab;
tab = (int**)malloc((800) * sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i<800; i++)
{
    tab[i] = (int*)malloc((600) * sizeof(int));
}
```

If you want your array to be 800x600. If you want it to be 600x800 just swap the values.

Comment: @AdamWaśniewski Glad it helped! If it solved your problem then maybe you could accept this answer?